# Attempting to use a parameterized MySQL SELECT statement in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm relatively new to Python and MySQL, and trying to build out a query that will target a specified table, column, and value. I was able to get it to work by stitching together
strings and the function inputs, but have been playing with parameters (%s) to see if I can accomplish the same task in a prettier fashion - is this possible?

Below is the working iteration of my (simplified) function:

```
def getRowbyString(a_table, a_col1, a_string):

  q = ("SELECT * FROM " + a_table + " WHERE " + "LOWER(" + a_col1 + ")" + " = '" + a_string + "'")

  qr = db.Cursor.execute(q)

  results = []

  for row in qr:
    results.append(row)
  
  return results
```

When I update my select statement, and cursor to use parameters a la:

```
q = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE LOWER(%s) = %s"

dbCursor.execute(q, (a_table, a_col1, a_string))
```

I am greeted with the following:
*ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''employees' WHERE LOWER('first_name') = 'saniya'' at line 1*.

Based on the above error I dont *think* it's possible because it **appears** to add apostrophes to the parameters. I'm hoping someone has a clever solution, or can tell me definitively that it can't be done.

Comment: Parameterization can be used for the values, but not the table name.

Comment: In line with the table name I'm assuming the column indicated in the where clause is out of the picture as well... cool beans, thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, parameterization cannot be used with identifiers, only values. Also if you are wanting a case insensitive comparison, using a [case insensitive (`*_ci`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-implementations.html) collation on the column will alleviate the need for `LOWER()` resulting in faster queries if the column is indexed. Welcome to StackOverflow. Keep asking good questions.